# Why are UV protective eyeware Orange?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision, absorption, laboratory-safety

Many industrial processes use uv as a curing agent.  When one uses such a process, one must protect one's eyes from the radiation.  Most uv protective gear I have seen is tinted orange?

Does this orange color come from the actual uv blocking chemicals, or is that color added for some user related reason (like being confident you picked up the right glasses)

Comment: Mostly the latter. My prescription glasses have a UV blocking coating on them, and it certainly isn't orange!

Comment: @JonCuster But eyeglass plastics are pretty much UV-blocking on their own, and those coatings only serve to coat the wallets of the folks selling you the glasses.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I'll test mine in the lab tomorrow, while wearing my orange laser goggles.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - that does not match my spectrometer's output. Yes, it is measurable, and quite nice to have for us folks living in really sunny places over 5000' altitude...

Comment: Another thought: Most kinds of plastic and glass are opaque to the "dangerous" UV wavelengths that cure plastic resins, kill germs, etc.  But, a lot of plastics and most glass _will_ transmit longwave UV (a.k.a., "black light") to some degree.  UV lamps in many applications are not filtered--they emit a spectrum that includes longwave UV lines and blue and green lines.  The orange dye in the glasses may be there to filter out longwave UV and visible light which both could be quite intense if you looked directly at the lamp.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: the power meter shows 3.12 mW (for an already attenuated 405 nm CW beam); after insertion of my polycarbonate spectacles, the reading  averages 2.70 mW. This is about 15% attenuation.  Thus UV protection is still required for the eyes with modern plastic lenses.

Comment: @PeterDiehr I don't know which I should be happier with: that my question has an answer, or that the question actually spawned empirical testing of polycarbonate lenses in defense of the answer!

Comment: @PeterDiehr  Thanks for providing detailed test results.  I agree that UV blocking is necessary in the lab;  I'll have to go off and take a look  the corneal damage rate for UV-A vs UV-B in sunlight-only conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [typical laser goggles](http://blog.phillips-safety.com/visible-light-laser-safety-glasses/) the color of lens is the color of light that is transmitted through the lens.  Thus if the lens is red, it will not protect you from laser beams that are in the red portion of the spectrum.

The color you are looking for will be, in some sense, the complementary color; since red-orange-pink are far from blue-violet-ultraviolet, these are the lens colors you would expect to work for UV light.

I have often worked with high power, class 3B and class 4, UV lasers, from 405 nm, which is UVA, down to 264 nm, which is beyond the UVB. The typical goggles which cover these ranges are orange to pink.

Your hypothesis is correct: the color comes from an [absorptive dye](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=762) which is incorporated into the plastic or glass.

It is also possible to apply [multi-layer optical coatings](http://www.allaboutvision.com/lenses/coatings.htm) to the lenses of spectacles which will preferentially reflect in the UV; this is a more expensive approach (hence dyes), and relies on destructive interference for the transmitted waves. The goal is to make make it transparent in the visible spectrum.